# Gradient of function of matrix exponential

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Suppose I have a differentiable function $\phi: \mathbb{R}^{p\times p} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ defined as $\phi(\exp(tA))$ where $t$ is a positive scalar and $A$ is a $p\times p$ real matrix.  How can I find gradient $\nabla \phi$ with respect to $A$?

Comment: As far as I know the exponental of a matrix id defined only for square martices.

Comment: @Taha can we assume that $p=q$?

Comment: I fixed the typo.  Now p = q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we have $\psi$ defined by
$$
\psi(A) = \phi(\exp(tA))
$$
The chain rule tells us that
$$
D_A\psi = [D\phi](\exp(tA)) [D_A \exp(tA)]
$$
The derivative of the exponential map may be taken as given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map), for example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Is it possible to point out a simpler article for derivative of just **matrix exponential**? I do not have the proper background in group theory and it takes some time to fully understand that article.

Comment: You might prefer [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_exponential_map), or perhaps something [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Identities) might help. It isn't going to be a nice function, at any rate.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you mean the answer will be far from being used in a practical gradient descent optimization algorithm?

Comment: @Taha actually, this might work well numerically.  One expression is a rapidly converging infinite sum, and the other is an integral.  It might be easy to get a good approximation... do you want me to clarify that infinite sum?

Comment: Thank you.  I also found a couple of papers on numerical computation.  After I read them, I will supplement your answer with explicit formulas for future reference of people like me who are just looking for explicit solutions :)

Comment: I realized that, computationally it was easier for me to insert the expansion of $\exp(tA)$ in the definition of $\phi(\cdot)$ and use a combination of product and chain rules to derive the gradient.